# How do you prepare styles without StylePropable mixin?

Tags: material-ui

Now that it's no longer recommended (or possible, given ES6 classes) to use the `StylePropable` mixin (and because libraries like react-mixin, that try to turn them into decorators have been nothing but trouble), and given that an official replacement hasn't been developed to my knowledge, what's the recommended way to incorporate the behavior (such as auto-prefixing) of the functions it provided, such as `prepareStyles`? I'm using `^0.14.0`.

Comment: In ES6 `StylePropable` is no more needed and will be removed. If you need to prepare style what about `Object.assign()`?